# How to remove part of a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm using Feedroll for showing RSS entries on my Tumblr.

Let's say I have:

```
document.write('<li class="rss-item"><a class="rss-item" href="http://mywebsite.com/arandomlink" target="_self"> [element1] element2 element3 element4</a><br />');
document.write('</li>');
```

element1 is a text "Thisismytext" (fixed length : 7)

element2 is a text "This Is My Text" (length not fixed)

element3 is a number "01" to "24" (fixed length : 2)

element4 is a text "THIS IS MY TEXT" (fixed length : 6 + space + 2)

(I have many entries and element1 and element4 don't change.)

I can't change the code from Feedroll or the titles of the entries.

Now, I would like to show my enrties (`[element1] element2 element3 element4`) like `element 2 - element 3`.

Example: `[Thisismytext] This Is My Text 05 OTHER TEXT` to `This Is My Text - 05`.

How do I do that?

I have tried split(), pop(), and substring() but I don't know how to use them.

And by the way, sorry for my English, I am French.

Comment: Try using regular expressions to match and parse the text values?

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly how to do that. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't receive the elements individually and are just getting a bunch of markup that you want to reformat...

If you are receiving the string of text and you want to strip out the different elements, you might want to use a regular expression to match the elements.

The following expression would just matches the text [element1] element2 element3 element4
with the constraints that you mentioned.

http://www.regexr.com/3959m

regular expression : `/\[(.{7})\]\s(.*)\s([0-9]{0,2})\s(.*)/g`

sample text : `[Thisism] This Is My Text 02 OTHER TEXT`

matches :

[image]

If you are receiving the full HTML string, you'd have to alter the regular expression to handle the html tags.

More info on regular expressions here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: I tried but I don't understand how to replace some elements of a string using regular expressions.

Comment: check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Okay so, I found how to do it :
`var re = /\[(.{7})\]\s(.*)\s([0-9]{0,2})\s(.*)/;
var str = "[Thisism] This Is My Text 02 OTHER TEXT";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2 - $3");`
But now, I would like to fetch every `<li class="rss-item"><a class="rss-item" href="http://mywebsite.com/arandomlink" target="_self"> [element1] element2 element3 element4</a><br /></li>` and automatically replace it with newstr. Is it possible?

Comment: sure.  with jQuery `$(".rss-item").each(function(rssItem) { // do your stuff here with rssItem.text()})` or `.html()`, you'll have to check

Comment: Btw, if it's more easy with PHP (I mean, the "search and replace" part), I have a private server.